# java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement cannot be cast to

Tags: spring, jaxb, spring-boot, unmarshalling

I am using Spring boot to call a webservice.

my config class is as:

```
@Configuration
public class ClientAppConfig {
@Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setPackagesToScan("com.client.stub");
    return marshaller;
}

@Bean
public ARTestClient arTestClient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
    ARTestClient client = new ARTestClient();
    client.setDefaultUri("uri");
    client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
    client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
   return client;
}
```

i am calling service as following:

```
    OutputMessageType response = (OutputMessageType) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(
            inputMessageType, new SoapActionCallback("http://Serviceuri"));
```

I am getting following error:

```
   [2016-03-18 14:45:43.697] boot - 10272 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-1] --- [dispatcherServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception 
  [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement 
  cannot be cast to com.wfs.client.stub.ar.OutputMessageType] with root cause
```

How to unMarshal the output from webservice????? 
How do i set unmarshaller for the response??

Answer (score 38):

Funny I JUST had the same issue, here's what I did :

Cast your response to a

```
JAXBElement<OutputMessageType>
```

So the result would be

```
JAXBElement<OutputMessageType> response = (JAXBElement<OutputMessageType>) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(
        inputMessageType, new SoapActionCallback("http://Serviceuri"));
// Then just call
System.out.println(response.getValue());
```

I have about the same configurations as you. I'm still trying to figure out why there's a ClassCastException. At least we have a workaround...

Comment: Don't you have unchecked warning then?

Comment: This is spot on my problem. I didn't specify my jaxb lib version in my pom.xml for my generated code. 2 years later, I regenerate my code, the newest version of Jaxb kicks in and my code gives me this cryptic error. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! it did help

Answer (score 10):

If it is still relevant today, there is a way to solve this issue in the config file. Instead of using **.setPackagesToScan** in the following line: `marshaller.setPackagesToScan("com.client.stub")` 

consider using **.setClassesToBeBound**

However, you will need to reference each class (that will be used for marshalling and unmarshalling) under your package:

```
   marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(new Class[] { 
       com.client.stub.Foo.class,
       com.client.stub.Bar.class,
       com.client.stub.Baz.class
   });
```

There is no need to cast to JAXBElement.

Answer (score 3):

```
    JAXBElement<OutputMessageType> response = (JAXBElement<OutputMessageType>) 
    getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(
    inputMessageType, new SoapActionCallback("http://Serviceuri"));
    // Then just call 
     System.out.println(response.getValue());
```

worked well for my case

Comment: Please add more to the answer that explains why the OP should use your code and how it solves their issue.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you define the root element in your xsd.
If you define it as

```
<element name="myRootElement" type="tns:myRootElementType" />
```

And then generate the JAXB classes - the unmarshaller will retrun JAXBElement after unmarshalling. And to get the root element you will have to call JAXBElement.getValue();

But if you define your root element as -

```
<element name="myRootElement">
       <complextType>
           Your definition of complex type - whatever it is
       </complexType>
<element>
```

and then generate your JAXB classes - the unmarshaller will return the entire object of your JAXB generated class that represents your root element. In this case it won't return object of JAXBElement.

You can check the documentation of Unmarshaller -

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html

Specifically sections -
**Unmarshal a root element that is globally declared**
and
**Unmarshal by Declared Type**

Remember - after making changes to your xsd - you will have to regenerate JAXB classes.

I hope this solves your problem.